# how to make an existing listbox autocomplete

Tags: ajax, entities

I have made a content type which has a list box field. now I need to change its widget to autocomplete but as you know list box fields does not have autocomplete widget. now I have added 650 contents of that type and changing the field type would be my last solution because I can't spend time in editing 650 contents!
so is there any way to add an autocomplete widget to the current list box field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list box field does not have `autocomplete` widget unless you use the `taxonomy` terms, and there are already 650 contents and you do not want to edit the content then you should use the Chosen module, the chosen module will allow you to search within the list. here is the examples page http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

following is the module page.
https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers Saïd! Suggestion: enhance your answer by including WHY you recommend this module, and maybe add a relevant quote from The project page. That will reduce the chance of downvoting ... Trust me ...

Comment: wow thanks that's a very useful module. but I prefer to do it programaticaly in order to have an appearance just like an autocomplete field. Isn't there any way?